# Apache BusyWorkers and BusyWorkers both are zero sometimes

Tags: apache-2.2

Sometimes I see interesting thing in apache server-status?auto output, busy and idle workers are zero sometimes, this confuses that whether apache was unresponsive or there is some other issue. Can anyone guide what should I look to dig more into this issue ?

```
BusyWorkers: 0
IdleWorkers: 0
Scoreboard: .................................................................W_...____________________________________________..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```